# How do I make it so when I hover over a site button it turns a different color

Tags: html, css

Sorry if I am not posting right but this is my first time using stackoverflow.

I am creating my website and I want the top nav links to change the background color on hover. Not the text but the area on the bar that spans from the top to the bottom. This is so that the user can signify that they are hovering over the certain link. This would also be used to make the website look better too. How would I do this?

```css
.header {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0; 
  clear: both;
  height: 80px;
  align-content: center;
  z-index: +2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header a:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
  #logo {
    position: sticky;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    width: 220px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px; /* if you want it vertically middle of the navbar. */
  }
  
  #navlist {
    float: right;
      /* if you want it vertically middle of the navbar */
}
    
    /* nav list style */
    li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: square;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 47.5px;  
    height: 80px;
}
        
/* link style */
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="homepage.html"><img id="logo" href="homepage.html" src="https://i.imgur.com/PTxdlc0.png"></a>
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="alliance.html">ALLIANCE</a></li>
    <li><a href="asp.html">ASP</a></li>
    <li><a href="diamondback.html">DIAMONDBACK</a></li>
    <li><a href="type.html">TYPE</a></li>
    <li><a href="info.html">INFO</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add the following code to your css:

```
.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

and change:

```
<li id="active"><a href="alliance.html">ALLIANCE</a></li>
```

**to**

```
<li class="active"><a href="alliance.html">ALLIANCE</a></li>
```

and then the link that is clicked (class = "active") will have the background color blue. you can change the color the way you want it

[solution could look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhBZP.png)

Answer (score 1):

You would simply move the `:hover` selector to the `<li></li>` surrounding the `<a></a>` tag set, and then ensure those list items extend from top to bottom.

```
ul#navlist li:hover { background-color: red; }
```